# Rails JS template won't render javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a Rails app that is acting weird when it comes to rendering a js template.

This is my update action (for a "message" model).

```
@message = Message.find_by_id(params[:id])
if @message.update_attributes(params[:message])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Then, in app/views/messages/update.js.erb, I've got this.

```
$(".active-status").html("hello world");
```

I've got JS that triggers the update (the user ticks a checkbox), the data comes through the controller correctly. But none of the JS I want to run inside the update template actually runs.

I put print statements before and after the JS above and it prints to the logs correctly. There are no errors in the server logs and no errors in the console.  When I run the line of JS mentioned above in the console, it works fine.  So what is going wrong with the template?

Comment: Post the code for the view this is updating. My guess is that you don't have '@messages' defined and you're iterating with an '.each' and getting '@messages = nil'.

Answer (score 0):

The browser console will not print out the errors if they're happening during the AJAX update. You can test this yourself by intentionally calling a nonexistent function from the js.erb file and verifying that it fails with print statements. This can be very misleading. So you should be 100% sure that you are seeing a print on the line directly after `$(".active-status").html("hello world");` when you click the checkbox.

This is how the prints should look when you're testing this. If you're not seeing both then there was a JS error, even if it wasn't reported in the JS console.

```
trace('BEFORE HELLO WORLD');
$(".active-status").html("hello world");
trace('AFTER HELLO WORLD');
```

EDIT

I'll add an example to clear the up the confusion.

```
<%logger.error "START OF JS.ERB FILE"%>
console.log('HELLO BEFORE ERROR');
alerts('hi'); // NOTE the JS errors at this point because 'alerts' is not defined, but the browser JS log never reports an error
$('#some_div_i_want_to_hide').hide(); // this never happens
console.log('HELLO AFTER ERROR');
<%logger.error "END OF JS.ERB FILE"%>
```

The rails server log will print out both the "START OF JS.ERB FILE" line and the "END OF JS.ERB FILE" line. My browser JS log prints out the line "HELLO BEFORE ERROR" but never prints out the line "HELLO AFTER ERROR." So the js.erb file continues to execute after the error but your js after the error never gets called.

Comment: "trace" isn't working for me.  Nothing is printing out anywhere.  Is that syntax definitely correct?  I added in a "<%= p 'inside update template' %>" line, which does print out to the server log. I'm at a loss as to how to troubleshoot from here.

Comment: I updated my answer to be more specific. I believe trace should work but you could also use console.log, which I used in my example in the edit. Make sure you are checking the browser JS log, not the rails server log.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Yeah, this had shed some light on the source problem: no js is being rendered inside the template at all.  Nothing is logging in the console, there are no errors with the alert, and the final logging statment doesn't appear either.  So I guess I'm left wondering how Rails can render this js template, but not process any javascript.  JS is rendering in similar JS templates in other parts of the app.  I'm not sure what makes this model different.